# Why am I getting TypeError: Person() takes no arguments with __init__() defined in class

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class Person:
    def __int__(self,name="Guido", job="Admin"):
        self.name=name
        self.job=job
```

Why am I getting  "TypeError: Person() takes no arguments" with the following code:

```
guido = Person(name='Guido', job='Sales')
```

Comment: Typo: `__int__` should be `__init__`

Comment: oh jeeze... I'm sorry to have bothered you with this.  I did not see that missing "i".

Comment: Don't sweat it. You're not the first to make this typo, won't be the last.